# Why the API throws Concurrent Modification Exception in next() of list iterator of the sub list in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrentmodification, sublist

This is in reference to the first level sub list of an arraylist.

We have this source code-

```
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public E next() {
            checkForComodification();
            int i = cursor;   // initially cursor is set to 0
            if (i >= SubList.this.size)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
            if (offset + i >= elementData.length)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();  // WHY? 
            cursor = i + 1;
            return (E) elementData[offset + (lastRet = i)];
        }
```

Why throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` instead of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Why concurrent?

---

**NOTE:-**

I am still struggling with the design part.

This is in reference to the comment by **@Kayaman**

Consider the below arraylist and its sublist-

```
el      original    sublist
0       a[0]
10      a[1]
20      a[2]        s[0]
30      a[3]        s[1]
40      a[4]        s[2]
50      a[5]        s[3]
60      a[6]        s[4]
70      a[7]
80      a[8]
90      a[9]
```

Every sublist has 2 instance variables

> parent offset - diff b/w the first index location of **parent** and sub
>   list.
>
> offset        - diff b/w the first index location of **original** and sub
>   list.

There is internally an array `elementData` which backs this `arraylist`
Even if some thread `removes` an element from the original arraylist (concurrent modification), the size gets reduced by `1`, but the `length` of elementData remains the same.

`fast remove` internally c/d by `remove(Object)`-

```
private void fastRemove(int index) {
    modCount++;
    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work
}
```

I see that this condition will never be fulfilled- 
`offset + i >= elementData.length` even after removal concurrently.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Presumably if the condition is true there has been a concurrent modification (I'd guess removal).

Comment: Why would you think it should throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` anyway, considering it throws `NoSuchElementException` a few lines before?

Comment: @AndyTurner: I was thinking of `ArrayList.this.size` than `SubList.this.size`.

Answer (score 4):

Because on creation of the `Sublist`, a range check is performed:

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    subListRangeCheck(fromIndex, toIndex, size);
    return new SubList(this, offset, fromIndex, toIndex);
}
```

So the `Sublist` will never go beyond the end of the source list.

Therefore, `offset + i` will always be inside the valid range of the original `List` *except* it has been modified in the meantime.

Note that `Sublist` takes any `AbstractList<>` as its source `List`; so even if `ArrayList` itself does not shrink its backing array on a remove, a subclass might do so - which would cause `Sublist` to be incorrect here.

Comment: Please update on the edited part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari Edited.

Comment: So `offset + i >= elementData.length` will never be true for the case as discussed above, not talking about any other sublists here.

Comment: Wouldn't `offset + i >= ArrayList.this.size` be correct?